Playing ogg audio files in react
I'm working on a React front-end, that needs to play audio files. I've got a backend service that give me ogg audio files that originate from WhatsApp conversations. The is played well in android browsers / desktop chrome  but not in Safari, on which its not supported. I only found really complex setups that do not work well with react, and require web workers and wasm for the decoding.(like this and this). These answers are "valid" But I could not find a (relatively) simple way to achieve this, and more React-ish way.

I think it's better to use library like "howler.js".
Official site
The advantage is ,from this tool you can convert 'ogg' files to 'Mp3' and that can play in any kind of browser.
first install "howler.js"
npm install howler

or
yarn add howler

Then create react component to send 'ogg' files to that component and convert them to 'Mp3'
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import { Howl } from 'howler';

const AudioPlayer = ({ src }) => {
  const soundRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
   
    soundRef.current = new Howl({
      src: [src],
      format: ['ogg', 'mp3'], // specify the formats you are providing
    });

   
    return () => {
      if (soundRef.current) {
        soundRef.current.unload();
      }
    };
  }, [src]);

  const playAudio = () => {
    if (soundRef.current) {
      soundRef.current.play();
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={playAudio}>Play Audio</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default AudioPlayer;

After that import this to your main.jsx or to app.jsx.

Thank you for the answer! but as you cant see from this there is only partial support for Safari:
https://github.com/goldfire/howler.js/issues/1330
as far as I can see the issue has not been fixed
